# Alpine: unsatisfiable constraints

Tags: docker, installation, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to install a package in alpine, in this case I specify 'jasper-dev', but it has happened to me with many others. The output I get in the terminal is:

```
/ # apk add jasper-dev
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
   jasper-dev (missing):
     required by: world [jasper-dev]
```

However when I search for the package at https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/, the package appears.
[image]

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
RUN echo "@testing http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk --update --no-cache add py3-numpy py3-pandas@testing \
      build-base \
      openblas-dev \
      unzip \
      wget \
      cmake \
      ca-certificates \
      libjpeg  \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
      jasper-dev \
      tiff-dev \
      libwebp-dev \
      clang-dev \
      linux-headers
```

How can I install this package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I show the version of alpine with `cat /etc/alpine-release` and see that it is the **3.12.0**. Then I search https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/ for the package **jasper-dev** in the branch **v3.12** and we see that it does not appear.
[image]

So we look in previous branches and see that it appears in **v3.10**, so I modify my Dockerfile to add that repo to `/etc/apk/repositories` with `RUN echo 'http: // dl-cdn. alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main ' >> /etc/apk/repositories`. This will install the package by executing the **docker build**